# Update facts module ansible

Tags: ansible

I have created a dict with set_fact. Now I want to update only the value "dnu" with the update_fact module.

```
"PortRCR": [
        {
            "desc": null,
            "dnu": "0",
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0",
            "os": "down"
        },
        {
            "desc": "Router",
            "dnu": "0",
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1",
            "os": "up"
        },
        {
            "desc": null,
            "dnu": "0",
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/10",
            "os": "down"
```

My playbook looks like that:

```
      set_fact:
        PortRCR: "{{ PortRCR + [{'name': item.key, 'desc': item.value.description, 'lp': item.value.lineprotocol | default('down', true), 'os': item.value.operstatus, 'dnu': '' | default('0', true) }] }}"
        PortRCR_length: "{{ PortRCR | length }}"
        cacheable: yes
      loop: "{{ ansible_net_interfaces | dict2items }}"
      vars:
        PortRCR: []

    - name: Update the fact
      ansible.utils.update_fact:
        updates:
        - path: PortRCR{{ item }}['dnu']
          value: "1"
      loop: "{{ range(0, PortRCR_length|int)|list }}"
```

Ansible tells me the fact was changed but the value is untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for the update_fact module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-utils-update-fact-module), you'll note that it says:

> Variables are not modified in place, instead they are returned by the module.

And all of the examples show the use of `register` to capture the udpated values, e.g:

```
- name: Update the fact
  ansible.utils.update_fact:
    updates:
    - path: a.b.c.0
      value: 10
    - path: "a['b']['c'][1]"
      value: 20
  register: updated
```

You need to add a `register` directive to your `update_fact` block, but we're going to need to post-process the returned value: because you're using register in a loop, you'll have multiple results in the `results` key (one per loop iteration).

This seems to work for me:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    # Here's the original fact as presented in your question
    - name: set portrcr fact
      set_fact:
        "PortRCR": [
          {
            "desc": null,
            "dnu": "0",
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0",
            "os": "down"
          },
          {
            "desc": "Router",
            "dnu": "0",
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1",
            "os": "up"
          },
          {
            "desc": null,
            "dnu": "0",
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/10",
            "os": "down"
          }]

    # We use update_fact to update the values and register
    # the results in the "updated" variable.
    - name: update portrcr fact
      ansible.utils.update_fact:
        updates:
          - path: "PortRCR[{{item}}].dnu"
            value: 1
      loop: "{{ range(PortRCR|length) }}"
      register: updated

    # The final iteration of the loop will contain all the changes,
    # so we want to replace the value of PortRCR with the value
    # from the final loop iteration.
    - set_fact:
        PortRCR: "{{ updated.results[-1].PortRCR }}"

    - debug:
        var: PortRCR
```

Running the above playbook produces:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "PortRCR": [
        {
            "desc": null,
            "dnu": 1,
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/0",
            "os": "down"
        },
        {
            "desc": "Router",
            "dnu": 1,
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1",
            "os": "up"
        },
        {
            "desc": null,
            "dnu": 1,
            "lp": "down",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/10",
            "os": "down"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it definitely helps me. Would it also be possible to only change the value of "dnu" when, for example, value "os" is changed?

Comment: Not entirely sure what what you're asking.  You can apply conditional `when` statements to your looping task, but I'm not sure what you mean by "when 'os' is changed'.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out by myself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: thanks, can we add conditions for each update in a single task and then write to the file at once?

Comment: @anand I'm not really clear what you're asking. You should probably [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide details about what you're trying to do.